# Postgres 9.5 конфликт при сохранении уникального индекса

Tags: postgresql

есть уникальный индекс на 2 поля.

как я могу при конфликте сохранить изменения?

```
INSERT INTO 
  "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
(

  "F_TagName_ID",
  "F_Date",
  "F_ConvertedValue"
)
VALUES (
  5,
  '2016-02-02 10:00:00',
  500
) ON CONFLICT index_fdate DO UPDATE set "F_ConvertedValue" = 510
```

не работает

Answer (score 1):

https://habrahabr.ru/post/264281/

нужно указывать оба поля, а не имя индекса

```
INSERT INTO 
  "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
(

  "F_TagName_ID",
  "F_Date",
  "F_ConvertedValue"
)
VALUES (
  5,
  '2016-02-02 10:00:00',
  500
) ON CONFLICT ("F_Date", "F_TagName_ID") DO UPDATE set "F_ConvertedValue" = 510
```